# Laravel Route::controller routing issue with prefix

Tags: laravel-routing, laravel-5

I have following implicit route defined (Laravel 5.2)

```
// Handle locale
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{country}/{language}',
], function () {
    Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
});
```

And here is my controller

```
class UserController extends BaseLocaleController
{
  public function getIndex()
  {
    return view('user/index');
  }

  public function getProfile($slug)
  {
    echo $slug;die;
    return view('user/view');
  }
}
```

My URI Structure is

> http://{host}/in/en/user/profile/manju

The problem here, my slug value is `in` instead of `manju`. Is there any URI pattern I need to apply?

How can make this work in Laravel 5.2. As you could see, I have `country` and `language` prefix in Route::group.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the $country, $language to the method

So it should be

```
 public function getProfile($country, $language, $slug)
  {
    echo $slug;die;
    return view('user/view');
  }
```